# google driveに置いたhtmlファイルを開く場合リンク

Tags: html, google-workspace

googel work spaceで契約しているdrive上にhtmlファイルを「リンクをクリップボードにコピー」のリンクからhtmlファイルをオープンすると、ただのテキストファイルとしてオープンしてしまいます。

こんな感じ↓

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これをブラウザで開く以下のようなアドレスになってしまいます。

```
file:///G:/マイドライブ/xxx/xxx....
```

htmlファイルを直接ブラウザで開けるようなアドレスの取得はどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
わざわざブラウザを選択なんかしないで、リンクを送ったら直接htmlで開けるようにしたいです。

Comment: Google Drive上からは直接HTMLファイルをrendered HTMLとして開くことはできないようです。そのため、今の場合、一つの回避策としてWeb Appsを介してrendered HTMLとして開くのはいかがでしょうか。 [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) Web Appsを使うと、URLを使って直接Google Drive上のHTMLをブラウザで開くことができます。ただ、この方法が想定しているゴールに含まれているかどうかわかりかねましたのでコメントとして提案させていただきました。

Comment: ご自身で作り以外にも、Webサービスで提供しているものもあります。[Drivetoweb](https://drv.tw/) 規約やセキュリティの制約がクリアできるならこういったものを利用することも検討してみてはいかがでしょう？

Comment: お二人ともありがとうございます。外部のアプリが今のところ使用禁止なのです
どうも無理っぽいので諦めて他の方法を探すようにします